# Using input to change directory path

Tags: python, shutil

I'm kinda new to python and I feel like the answer to this is so simple but I have no idea what the answer is. I'm trying to move files from one place to another but I don't want to have to change my code every time I wanna move that file so I just want to get user input from the terminal.

```
    import shutil

    loop = True
    while loop:
        a = input()
        shutil.move("/home/Path/a", "/home/Path/Pictures")
```

What do I have to put around the a so that it doesn't read it as part of the string?

Comment: shutil.move("/home/Path/{0}".format(a), "/home/Path/Pictures")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want. the `os.path.join()` will combine the string value in a, that you get from input with the first part of the path you have provided. You should use os.path.join() as this will form paths in a way that is system independent.

```
import shutil
import os

loop = True

while loop:
    a = input()
    shutil.move(os.path.join("/home/Path/", a), "/home/Path/Pictures")
```

Output:

```
>>> a = input()
    test.txt
>>> path = os.path.join("/home/Path/", a)
>>> path
    '/home/Path/test.txt'
```

You can also use `"/home/Path/{0}".format(a)` which will swap the value of a with `{0}`, or you can do do `"/home/Path/{0}" + str(a)` which will also do what you want.

Edited to account for Question in comment:

This will work if your directory doesn't have any sub-directories. it may still work if there are directories and files in there but I didn't test that.
    import shutil
    import os

```
files = os.listdir("/home/Path/")
for file in files:
    shutil.move(os.path.join("/home/Path/", file), "/home/Path/Pictures")
```

Comment: What if i'm only trying to move the all the contents within the folder but not the folder?

Comment: @Asori12 edited and added a simple way way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

one solution

```
a = 'test.csv'
path = '/home/Path/{}'.format(a)

>>> path
/home/Path/test.csv
```